The instance of entity type 'GoodsDelivery' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked
var existingRecord = await this.GetGoodsDelivery(goodsDelivery.Id);

var detailIdsInNewRecord = new HashSet<int>(goodsDelivery.GoodsDeliveryDetail.Select(d => d.Id));

foreach(var record in existingRecord.GoodsDeliveryDetail.ToList())
{
    if(!detailIdsInNewRecord.Contains(record.Id))
    {
        inventoryContext.GoodsDeliveryDetail.Remove(record);
        
    }
}

foreach(var newrecord in goodsDelivery.GoodsDeliveryDetail.ToList())
{
    if(newrecord.Id == 0)
    {
        var newDetailRow = new GoodsDeliveryDetail();
        var newrecordType = newrecord.GetType();
        var properties = newrecordType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(newrecord);
            property.SetValue(newDetailRow, value);
        }


        goodsDelivery.GoodsDeliveryDetail.Add(newDetailRow);
    }
}

inventoryContext.GoodsDelivery.Update(goodsDelivery);       
await inventoryContext.SaveChangesAsync();

error occurs

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'GoodsDelivery' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

var existingRecord = await this.GetGoodsDelivery(goodsDelivery.Id);

var detailIdsInNewRecord = new HashSet<int>(goodsDelivery.GoodsDeliveryDetail.Select(d => d.Id));

foreach(var record in existingRecord.GoodsDeliveryDetail.ToList())
{
    if(!detailIdsInNewRecord.Contains(record.Id))
    {
        inventoryContext.GoodsDeliveryDetail.Remove(record);
        
    }
}

foreach(var newrecord in goodsDelivery.GoodsDeliveryDetail.ToList())
{
    if(newrecord.Id == 0)
    {
        var newDetailRow = new GoodsDeliveryDetail();
        var newrecordType = newrecord.GetType();
        var properties = newrecordType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(newrecord);
            property.SetValue(newDetailRow, value);
        }


        goodsDelivery.GoodsDeliveryDetail.Add(newDetailRow);
    }
}

inventoryContext.GoodsDelivery.Update(goodsDelivery);       
await inventoryContext.SaveChangesAsync();


Do not call GoodsDelivery.Update(goodsDelivery) and try again.
